# Installing extra texlive packages in centos

Tags: centos, fedora, yum, latex

I'm new to CentOS (always used ubuntu and similar) and I am trying to compile some latex code here for the first time. So there's a big list of `.sty` that are needed.

I was able to install some by hand since I found them using `yum search`, but others aren't available in the CentOS's repos (like `upquote.sty`). I know I could download them from CTAN manually, but I can't practically do this for the whole list. Is there a way to add the 'texlive-collection' to which the `.sty` belongs, add it to the repo and download it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`upquote.sty` at least is in the Centos 6 repo, so could be installed via the `texlive-texmf-latex-2007-39.el6_7.noarch` package.

```
$ sudo yum whatprovides '*/upquote.sty'
...
texlive-texmf-latex-2007-39.el6_7.noarch : Texmf files needed for 
...
Filename    : /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
```

If the vintage of texlive offered in the vendor packages is too out of date, then [installing the latest version](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) to some not-vendor directory (e.g. your home dir) will be a better option; with the latest version comes the [`tlmgr` utility](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages), to which a list of `*.sty` files could easily be fed:

```
$ cat pkglist
noto.sty
upquote.sty
$ tlmgr install `perl -ple 's/.sty//' pkglist`
tlmgr: package repository http://...
tlmgr install: package already present: noto
tlmgr install: package already present: upquote
$
```

Comment: That package isn't available anymore. Also, `upquote` was just an example. I'd like to find a general method that will work on other packages as well.